# How to submit a form with a post, then delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a rails form I'd like to have first post changes, then delete a record. I'm making a form to cancel an account, and I'd like to allow the user to explain why they are cancelling the account. Thus, the form must submit a post for the the text field explaining why they are cancelling, followed by sending a delete to cancel the account.

```
<%= form_for account, url: account_url(account) do |f| %>
    <label class="account_mini-headers">Support Ticket</label>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>

    <label class="account_mini-headers">Notes</label>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>

    <%= f.button "Cancel" %>
<% end %>
```

This code will successfully submit the form, but will not issue the delete request to cancel the account. However the text fields get saved.

```
<%= button_to('Destroy', account_path(account), method: :delete) %>
```

Replacing f.button with this button_to issues the delete, but doesn't post the form changes.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just sending the form via the :delete method, and creating the new record in the #destroy method in the controller?

Comment: @steel I had a brain fart, I forgot to include creation code in the destroy method. If you post this as an answer, I'll close the question and mark you as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly done as one procedure in the `#destroy` method. Send the form via `:delete` and create your new record right before you destroy (or better yet - deactivate?) the account.

Answer (score 0):

Some Thing Came across my sight hour Ago... Might be this idea Can Help yu out..

[Deleting an image only after the form is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894199/deleting-an-image-only-after-the-form-is-submitted)